# Ошибка при определении информации об системы в Windows XP C#

Tags: c#, windows

В образовательных целях, разрабатываю программу, которая показывает нужную мне информацию о системе. Следующим кодом я вывожу инфу о системе в консоль

```
using System;
using System.Management;   //This namespace is used to work with WMI classes. For using this namespace add reference of System.Management.dll .
using Microsoft.Win32;     //This namespace is used to work with Registry editor.

namespace OperatingSystemInfo1
{
    public class SystemInfo
    {
        private static string pcname;
        private static string username;
        private static string osname;
        private static string osarch;
        private static string osvers;
        private static string processors;
        private static int count_proc;
        private static string avname = "Undefined";
        private static string avtype = "Unknown";
        private static string avstatus = "Unknown";
        public void getOperatingSystemInfo()
        {
            try
            {
                pcname = Environment.MachineName;
                username = Environment.UserName;
                count_proc = Environment.ProcessorCount;
                // Console.WriteLine("Displaying operating system info....\n");
                //Create an object of ManagementObjectSearcher class and pass query as parameter.
                ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem");
                foreach (ManagementObject managementObject in mos.Get())
                {
                    if (managementObject["Caption"] != null)
                    {
                        osname = managementObject["Caption"].ToString();   //Display operating system caption
                    }
                    if (managementObject["OSArchitecture"] != null)
                    {
                        osarch = managementObject["OSArchitecture"].ToString();   //Display operating system architecture.
                    }
                    if (managementObject["CSDVersion"] != null)
                    {
                        osvers = managementObject["CSDVersion"].ToString();     //Display operating system version.
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Op: 1 \n"+ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        public void getProcessorInfo()
        {
           // Console.WriteLine("\n\nDisplaying Processor Name....");
            RegistryKey processor_name = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);   //This registry entry contains entry for processor info.

            if (processor_name != null)
            {
                if (processor_name.GetValue("ProcessorNameString") != null)
                {
                    processors = processor_name.GetValue("ProcessorNameString").ToString();  //Display processor ingo.
                }
            }
        }

        public static bool AntivirusInstalled()
        {

            try
            {
                string wmipathstr = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + @"\root\SecurityCenter2";
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(wmipathstr, "SELECT * FROM AntivirusProduct");
                ManagementObjectCollection instances = searcher.Get();
                return instances.Count > 0;
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Op: 2 \n" + e.Message);
            }

            return false;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SystemInfo si = new SystemInfo();       //Create an object of SystemInfo class.
                si.getOperatingSystemInfo();            //Call get operating system info method which will display operating system information.
                si.getProcessorInfo();                  //Call get  processor info method which will display processor info.
                bool returnCode = AntivirusInstalled();
                // Console.WriteLine("Antivirus Installed " + returnCode.ToString());
                var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\SecurityCenter2",
                                                "SELECT * FROM AntiVirusProduct");

                // это цикл по найденным антивирусам
                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    string displayName = (string)queryObj["displayName"]; // имя
                    avname = $"Antivirus: {displayName}";
                    if (avname == null || avname == "") avname = "null";

                    uint productState = (uint)queryObj["productState"];
                    uint secutityProvider = (productState & 0xff0000) >> 16; // что умеет

                    if ((secutityProvider & 1) != 0) avtype = "firewall";
                    if ((secutityProvider & 2) != 0) avtype = "autoupdate settings";
                    if ((secutityProvider & 4) != 0) avtype = "antivirus";
                    if ((secutityProvider & 8) != 0) avtype = "antispyware";
                    if ((secutityProvider & 16) != 0) avtype = "internet settings";
                    if ((secutityProvider & 32) != 0) avtype = "user account control";
                    if ((secutityProvider & 64) != 0) avtype = "service";
                    uint realtimeStatus = (productState & 0xff00) >> 8; // realtime-защита
                                                                        //  Console.Write("Realtime status: ");
                    switch (realtimeStatus)
                    {
                        case 0x00:
                            avstatus = "off";
                            // Console.WriteLine("off");
                            break;
                        case 0x01:
                            avstatus = "expired";
                            // Console.WriteLine("expired");
                            break;
                        case 0x10:
                            avstatus = "on";
                            // Console.WriteLine("on"); 
                            break;
                        case 0x11:
                            avstatus = "snoozed";
                            //Console.WriteLine("snoozed");
                            break;
                        default:
                            avstatus = "unknown";
                            // Console.WriteLine("unknown"); 
                            break;
                    }

                    uint signatureStatus = (productState & 0xff); // состояние сигнатур
                                                                  // Console.Write("Signature status: ");
                    switch (signatureStatus)
                    {
                        case 0x00:
                            // Console.WriteLine("up to date");
                            break;
                        case 0x10:
                            // Console.WriteLine("oout of date"); 
                            break;
                        default:
                            // Console.WriteLine("unknown"); 
                            break;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Op: 3 \n" + ex.ToString());
            }
                Console.WriteLine(pcname + "\n" + username + "\n" + osname + "\n" + osarch + "\n" + osvers + "\n" + processors + "\n" + count_proc + "\n" + avname + "\n" + avtype + "\n" + avstatus);
                Console.Read();
            }
    }
}
```

Начиная с Windows 7 программа работает правильно и показывает нужную мне информацию. Однако если запустить её в Windows XP, вызываются следующие ошибки

> System.Management.ManagementException: Не найден
>          в System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatu
>       s errorCode)
>          в System.Management.PropertyData.RefreshPropertyInfo()
>          в System.Management.PropertyDataCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
>          в System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String
>   propertyName
>       )
>          в System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Item(String propertyName)
>          в OperatingSystemInfo1.SystemInfo.getOperatingSystemInfo()
>       Недопустимое пространство имен
>       System.Management.ManagementException: Недопустимое пространство имен
>          в System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatu
>       s errorCode)
>          в System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o)
>          в System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
>          в System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Initialize()
>          в System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Get()
>          в OperatingSystemInfo1.SystemInfo.Main(String[] args)
>       PC-2B1EFDE
>       Администратор
>       Microsoft Windows XP Professional
>
> ```
>        Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz
> 2
> Undefined
> Unknown
> Unknown
> ```

Как я заметил, разрядность системы Windows XP программа тоже не смогла определить. Как исправить, чтоб программа работала на всех системах?

Comment: приведите минимальный код, [в соответствии с правилами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), тогда вам быстрее помогут!

Comment: У меня ошибки вызываются при всех методах. Поэтому показал полный код.

Comment: Под какую версию фреймворка программа скомпилирована и какая версия на XP стоит?

Comment: а какой разрядности Windows XP которая не работает корректно и Windows 7/8 или любая другая которая работает?

Comment: Программа скомпилирована под версию 3.0, а на XP стоит 3.5. У Windows XP разрядность x86, а на Windows 7 x64, Windows 8.1 тоже x64

Comment: Собственно, а все ли свойства существуют в WMI-классе Win32_OperatingSystem для WinXP? или WMI-подсистема неправильно функционирует на WinXP. Проверьте список свойств в консоли командой **wmic path Win32_OperatingSystem get /value** на WinXP.

Comment: А пространство имен **\root\SecurityCenter2** навряд ли существует в Windows XP